# Checkboxes True or False not loading into form properly

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm using a ModelForm to load a Form and all of the values are pulling properly except the checkboxes. They always load in unchecked whether or not their state is True or False.

I've tried creating the checkbox fields like:

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" checked='{{ form.instance.hot }}'>
        <span>Hot{{ form.hot }}</span>
</label>
<li>CSR: {{ form.csr }}</li>
{% if request.user|has_group:"Customer Service Manager" %}
     <li>Documents: {{ form.documents }}</li>
{% endif %}
<li>Notes: {{ form.notes }}</li>
<li>First Name:{{ form.first_name }}</li>
<li>Last Name: {{ form.last_name }}</li>
<li>Address: {{ form.address }}</li>
```

Which results in the checkbox always being checked instead matching what's in the table for that client.

models.Client

```py
class Client(models.Model):
    #Account Information
    client_status =[("1", "Active"), ("0", "Inactive")]
    WHOPAYS =[("0", "Not Applicable"), ("1", "They Pay"), ("2", "We Pay")]
    hot = models.BooleanField(default=False, required=False)
    region = models.ForeignKey('Region', to_field='region_id', on_delete=None, null=True, blank=True)
    sub_account = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='sub_account_of_client', null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateField('Account Creation', auto_now_add=True)
    client_class = models.ForeignKey('ClientClass', on_delete=None, null=True, blank=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey('ClientCategory', on_delete=None, null=True, blank=True)
    they_pay = models.BooleanField('They Pay', default = False, required=False)
    we_pay = models.BooleanField('We Pay', default = False, required=False)
    csr = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, to_field='extension', on_delete=None, blank=True, null=True, limit_choices_to= Q( groups__name = 'Customer Service'))
    #Upload location /<ClientID>/documents/*
    documents = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to=client_directory_path)
    notes = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    active_status = models.CharField('Status', max_length=1, choices=client_status, default="1")
    client = models.CharField('Client/Company Name',max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    account_number = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    #Contact Information
    first_name = models.CharField('First Name', max_length = 200, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField('Last Name', max_length = 200, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length = 254, null=True, blank=True)
    main_phone = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=50)
    alt_phone = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=50)
    fax = PhoneField(null=True, blank=True)
    follow_up = models.DateField('Date to Follow Up', default=three_days())
    #Billing and Shipping Addresses
    address = models.CharField('Address Line 1', max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    address2 = models.CharField('Address Line 2', max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField('City', max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    zipcode = models.CharField('Zip Code', max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    state = models.CharField('State', max_length=2, null=True, blank=True, choices=STATE_CHOICES)
    country = models.CharField('Country', max_length=200, null=True, blank=True, default='USA')

    def __str__(self):
        if self.sub_account:
            return '{0}: Sub-Account for {1}'.format(self.client, self.sub_account)
        else:
            return '{0} - {1}'.format(self.client, self.zipcode)
```

views.client_view

```py
def client_view(request):
    FormSet = modelformset_factory(Client, form=ClientSheet, extra=0)  
    if request.method == 'POST':  
        formset = FormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)  
        if formset.is_valid():
                formset.save(commit=False)
                formset.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/client/')
    else:  
        query = Client.objects.filter(follow_up__lte=date.today(), csr__extension=request.user.extension).order_by('-hot')
        currentcall = Client.objects.filter(follow_up__lte=date.today(), csr__extension=request.user.extension).order_by('-hot').first()
        paginator = Paginator(query, 1)  # Show 1 forms per page  
        page = request.GET.get('page')  
        try:  
            objects = paginator.page(page)  
        except PageNotAnInteger:  
            objects = paginator.page(1)  
        except EmptyPage:  
            objects = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)  
        page_query = Client.objects.filter(id__in=[object.id for object in objects])  
        formset = FormSet(queryset=page_query)  
        context = {'objects': objects, 'formset': formset, 'callqueue': query, 'currentcall': currentcall}  
        return render(request, 'main/client.html', context)
```

Comment: Why are you doing that, rather than using the formset in the template?

Comment: If you mean by including the <input> and <span> tags it's due to using MaterializeCSS. Without those the form renders with just the text and no checkbox.

I'm still new with forms, I've looked through tons of documentation to get all of the fields to pull properly to no avail.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I updated the code sample to include some other fields for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever Checkbox will **always** be checked as soon as you pass `checked` attribute.

Your template should look like

```
<input type="checkbox" {{ form.instance.hot|yesno:"checked,'',''" }}>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I hadn't seen anything about that in the docs. I'd give it an upvote because I think it will help a lot of people but it's my first question and I have 1 reputation ha ha.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are providing model instance for the form, you can use `__init__` method of your form:

```py
# forms.py

class ClientForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = (
            ...
            hot,
            ...
        )
        widgets = {
            'hot': forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={}),
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance:
            self.fields['hot'].widget.attrs['checked'] = self.instance.__getattribute__('hot')
```